# Where am I going wrong implementing Kendall's tau

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

So I found this article on how to calculate Kendall's tau very efficiently O(n log n). But I don't seem to be able to get it right.

In the article the flow of code is explained conceptually and code example at the bottom. I am trying to implement the SDTau variant.
I am getting values such as -1.5 with an array of testing numbers which is simply not possible for Kendall's tau. It should be between -1 and 1.

Link: [no login required, open fulltext or download pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226498574_Fast_algorithms_for_the_calculation_of_Kendall%27s_t)

My code

```
class Kendall_Correlation
{

public static double RUN(List<XYPoint> XY)
{
    List<XYPoint> SortedByXThenY = new List<XYPoint>();
    SortedByXThenY = XY.OrderBy(XYPoint => XYPoint.X).ThenBy(XYPoint => XYPoint.Y).ToList();

    SortedSet<double> tree = new SortedSet<double>();

    int NumBefore = 0;
    int Equals = 0;
    int Discordant = 0;
    int concordant = 0;
    int ExtraX = 0;
    int EXtraY = 0;
    int ACount = 0;
    int BCount = 0;
    int CCount = 0;
    int DCount = 0;
    int ECount = 0;
    double PreviousX = SortedByXThenY[0].X;
    double PreviousY = SortedByXThenY[0].Y;
    tree.Add(SortedByXThenY[0].Y);

    for (int i = 1; i < SortedByXThenY.Count; i++)
    {
        if (SortedByXThenY[i].X == PreviousX)
        {
            DCount = 0;
            ECount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (SortedByXThenY[i].Y == PreviousY)
            {
                ECount++;
            }
            else
            {
                DCount += ECount;
                ECount = 1;
            }
        }

        tree.Add(SortedByXThenY[i].Y);

        Equals = tree.Where(node => node == SortedByXThenY[i].Y).Count();
        NumBefore = tree.Where(node => node < SortedByXThenY[i].Y).Count();

        ACount = NumBefore - DCount;
        BCount = Equals - ECount;
        CCount = i - (ACount + BCount + DCount + ECount - 1);
        EXtraY += DCount;
        ExtraX += BCount;
        concordant += ACount;
        Discordant += CCount;
        PreviousX = SortedByXThenY[i].X;
        PreviousY = SortedByXThenY[i].Y;
    }

    int n0 = concordant + Discordant + ExtraX;
    int n1 = concordant + Discordant + EXtraY;

    double tau = ((Double) concordant - (Double) Discordant) / Math.Sqrt(n0 * n1);
    return tau;
}

public class XYPoint
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

Is it because I am using a `SortedSet` Type? From my understanding a `SortedSet` is basically identical to a AVL Tree? My code is also considerably slower than the depicted times it takes in the article. Mine is more in the magnitude of minutes when trying with a sample of 1,000,000

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  You have `SortedByXThenY` declared twice.  And `XYPoints` doesn't exist.  Should that be the method param `XY` instead?  Can you fix so others can run this?

Comment: @Zer0 Apologies, the issues should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` method iterates over the entire `SortedSet` to find elements that satisfy the given condition. This has an O(n) cost, so your function has an overall asymptotic running time of O(n<sup>2</sup>), not O(n log n) as you assumed.

For an efficient implementation of the operation you are doing on the SortedSet (finding the number of nodes whose values are greater than, or equal to, a given value), you can use an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree).

Comment: You would assume that its log n time since its essentially a binary tree and it should be effectively halving the set for every time it chooses node.left or node.right. How would I go about doing it with log n instead?

Comment: @CodeMuppet [Enumerable.Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) is a generic method that is designed to work with anything that implements IEnumerable (which may be an array, linked list, tree or any other iterable data structure). It does not have any special case for a SortedSet where a more efficient algorithm can be used. The only SortedSet methods with log(n) cost are Add, Remove, Contains, Min and Max. If you cannot express your algorithm in terms of these operations, you will have to skip SortedSet and implement everything yourself.